# How to edit buddypress templates?

Tags: buddypress

I am using a child theme of twentyten.  I have installed buddypress but I need to edit the templates so I can add in my sidebar.  But 1.  I cannot find the right template to edit the category page which shows all my forums under that category and 2. I am reading about creating a buddypress child theme, but as I see it, this is just a wordpress child theme, and I alreayd have this.  Please help if you can.

Comment: please anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPress themes are WordPress themes, plus extra templates. I encourage you to use the BuddyPress Template Pack plugin to enable these extra templates: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-template-pack/

Here's a bit of background on how to build a BP-compatible child theme: http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/bp-template-pack-walkthrough-level-easy-2/

This link actually uses TwentyTen as an example: http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/theme-dev-bp-template-pack-walkthrough-twenty-ten-bp-1-5/

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking how to make a custom category template for buddypress, you probably found what i did... there isnt a category.php template in the bp-default theme; however, you can copy the archive.php template and rename it category-slug.php (slug being the url friendly category name) and boom winning.